# Confusion with position vector for torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

Let's say we have a particle of mass $M$ attached to a point $P_0$ by some massless rod of length $T$ and it is undergoing circular motion at a constant angular velocity.

There is more to this problem, but my confusion only lies here. We define torque as $\mathbf{\tau}=\mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{F}$ where $r$ is the position vector which in this specific case gets us from $P_0$ to our particle. In my textbook it says the torque is $MgT\sin(\theta)-F_{cent}T\cos(\theta)$ where $F_{cent}$ is the centripetal force acting on the particle.

How do we arrive at this result? I understand our position vector is $T\sin(\theta)-T\cos(\theta)$, but I don't understand how our force is defined in the equation for torque. A cross product of $(T\sin(\theta)-T\cos(\theta))\times (Mg+F_{cent})$ wouldn't give me the result defined above. What am I missing? If it helps, this is a first-year mechanics class.

Comment: it looks like there is mistake in the textbook. The centripetal force is parallel to radius vector, so it cannot survive the cross product.

Comment: What you are missing is a sketch which defines the situation and symbols.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand our position vector is $T\sin(\theta)−T\cos(\theta)$...
>
> A cross product of $(T\sin(\theta)−T\cos(\theta))×(Mg+F_\text{cent})$...

$T\sin(\theta)−T\cos(\theta)$ isn't a vector quantity. Hence it also does not make sense to take the "cross product" of it with the force vectors. Hint: figure out what the $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{F}$ vectors are (both magnitude and direction), then try calculating the cross product of those vectors.

Comment: Would $\textbf{r}$ be $T$sin$(\theta)\hat{r}-T$cos$(\theta)\hat{z}$?

Comment: Well my first response would be no, but I'd also say that I don't know what your $\hat r$, $\hat z$ and $\theta$ quantities are :)